# Git message type on library update

Tags: node.js, git, version-control

I make my own react boilerplate and come until updating packages. So I've update react across major version (v15x to v16x), and change my code on a module file called `injectReducer`. So what i've changed in `injectReducer` is from this:

```
static contextTypes = {
  store: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};
```

to this:

`static contextType = ReactReduxContext;`

Now I think this doesn't do any breaking changes on my boilerplate, because the **use** of the module still the same (backward compatible). But what about the package I've updated? Should any library updated across major is considered breaking changes? What about minor updates?

Here is my full code of `injectReducer`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { ReactReduxContext } from 'react-redux';
import hoistNonReactStatics from 'hoist-non-react-statics';

import getInjectors from './reducerInjectors';

export default ({ key, reducer }) => (WrappedComponent) => {
  class ReducerInjector extends React.Component {
    static WrappedComponent = WrappedComponent;
    static displayName = `withReducer(${(WrappedComponent.displayName || WrappedComponent.name || 'Component')})`;
    static contextType = ReactReduxContext;

    injectors = getInjectors(this.context.store);

    componentWillMount() {
      const { injectReducer } = this.injectors;

      injectReducer(key, reducer);
    }

    render() {
      return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />;
    }
  }

  return hoistNonReactStatics(ReducerInjector, WrappedComponent);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

> But what about the package I've updated? Should any library updated across major is considered breaking changes?

That is the idea behing the major version [in semver](https://semver.org/)

> when you make incompatible API changes

Except I would consider it does not involve just the API.
See as an example "[Semantic Versioning, Go Modules, and Databases](https://blog.dgraph.io/post/serialization-versioning/)" (just to illustrate the kind of non-API change which would still warrant a major version bump)

Basically, if any client of your library has work to do in order to adapt to the new version... your change should be considered major.
If not: minor.